# Pi 3 not turning on red LED only lights up and the green LED lights up for 2 seconds before turning off

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, power-supply

I am trying to turn my Pi on but it is not turning on. Only the red LED remains on without blinking. The green LED is on during startup for 2 seconds and then turns off.

I have tried many power sources, it was working fine but suddenly started doing this problem. Yesterday it showed the same problem but was working again after some time but this time it does not.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Does the green LED stay on solid for 2 seconds or does it flash multiple times in the 2 seconds?

Comment: multiple times in 2 seconds

Comment: Could you please tell me the exact number of times it flashes.

Answer (score 1):

The number of times the green LED flashes indicates what the problem is:

For Pi's running firmware before 20th October 2012:

- 2 flashes: The SD Card cannot be read
- 3 flashes: loader.bin not found
- 4 flashes: loader.bin not launched
- 5 flashes: start.elf not found
- 6 flashes: start.elf not launched
- 7 flashes: kernel.img not found

For newer firmware versions, so this will apply:

- 3 flashes: start.elf not found
- 4 flashes: start.elf not launched
- 7 flashes: kernel.img not found
- 8 flashes: SDRAM not recognised. You need newer bootcode.bin/start.elf firmware

I think the quickest fix is to backup anything important on the SD card. And try installing Raspbian again but on a different SD card.

Answer (score 0):

**On the Rpi3, you should get a steady red light.  That indicates proper voltage.**

**Then you should get a 2 second green light as it mounts the SD card.**

**Then after a few seconds there should be a steady green then some flashing as it boots.**

===>  If you are not getting that steady green then it is not booting.

===>  If you are not getting a steady red then the voltage is too low.

---

Sometimes, during boot, it will activate a device, maybe even a USB WiFi adapter, which pulls the voltage just low enough that the boot process can't complete yet the red light stays on.

The test for that is to pull out the WiFi adapter and then see if the system will boot up.  Then when it shows the solid green for a while you can hot-plug in the WiFi adapter.

If that's the case then I replace the power supply cable to eliminate that as a cause.

---

**Always make sure you have good image backups of your SD cards, using [Win32DiskImager](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/win32diskimager).**